# NullPointerException when i do insert into database (android)

Tags: android, database, insert

i have some data to write in data base (three strings);
i have a **private class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper**
and i have **dataBase = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();**
When i do dataBase.insert()  i have a nullPointerException.

i checked my data in debuger for write and they don't equal to null;

DBHelper:

```
private class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper { //for write and read data from DB

static final String GROUPPS = "groupps";
static final String IMPORTANCE = "importance";
static final String NAME_OF_TABLE = "Person";
static final String PERSON_KEY = "perskey";

    private static final String MY_QUERY = "CREATE TABLE " + NAME_OF_TABLE + " ( " +
            PERSON_KEY + " TEXT, " +
            GROUPPPS + " TEXT, " +
            IMPORTANCE + " TEXT);";

    public DBHelper(Context context) {
        // constructor of superclass
        super(context, "MyDBB", null, 2);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        Log.d("", "--- onCreate database ---");
        db.execSQL(MY_QUERY);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

    }
}
```

my method for write data on the dataBase:

```
 public void writeDataToDB(ArrayList<Person> arrayList) {

    contentValues = new ContentValues();
    dbHelper = new DBHelper(activity.getApplicationContext());
    dataBase = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();


    for (int i = 0; i < arrayList.size(); i++) {

        contentValues.put(PERSON_KEY, arrayList.get(i).getKey());
        contentValues.put(GROUPPPS, arrayList.get(i).getGroup());
        contentValues.put(IMPORTANCE, String.valueOf(arrayList.get(i).isImportant()));

        Log.e("writeDataToDB", "Start inserting " + contentValues.toString());
        long rowID = dataBase.insert(NAME_OF_TABLE, null, contentValues);
        Log.e("writeDataToDB - ", "Value inserted, rowID = " + rowID);
        contentValues.clear();
    }

}
```

And in my method i have exception at line :
long rowID = dataBase.insert(NAME_OF_TABLE, null, contentValues);
and rowID = -1  it means - somthing wrong;

and my LogCat:

```
Error inserting groupp=Withoutgroup importance=false perskey=0r2-2B43414D272B4D16
    android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: table Persons has no column named groupp: , while compiling: INSERT INTO Persons(groupp,importance,perskey) VALUES (?,?,?)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Group](http://sqlite.org/lang_select.html) is a keyword so if your  table has this as column name then that may be problem.
see

```
group=Without group
```

Comment: I renamed all GROUP to GROUPPS (For test); 
and now i have another problem (I changed LogCat on my post).
But my query have this column...

Comment: I solved my problem.. 

Problem it's a reserved keyword "group on SQLite".  Then i haved the old DataBase on my Emulator..  thx for you help.

Comment: check the diff. between >>>>static final String GROUPPS = "groupps"; and table Persons has no column named groupp:>>>>notice the 's'

Answer (score 1):

"importance=false group=Without group perskey=0r114343434343434343434343434343434343434343434343"

You have to put Without group inside single quotes, like this: `'Without group'`, or else SQLite will think the second word is part of the SQL query.

Comment: Try to put all text you insert to the database between quotes. An alternate hypothesis would be that SQLite simply isn't very fond of using SQL keywords as column names (like group).

Comment: I solved my problem.. 

Problem it's a reserved keyword "group on SQLite".  Then i haved the old DataBase on my Emulator..  thx for you help.